# Loading JSON File without using an URL?

Tags: json, rest, web-services, openapi, redoc

I created a JSON document for an OpenApi Restful service. I was wondering if there is anyway to load the json file without using an outsource website. Sorry if this is a dumb question im new to OpenApi.

Here is the html code;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>ReDoc</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    redoc {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700|Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <redoc spec-url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/json" ></redoc>
  <script src="redoc.standalone.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to load the json file without the spec-url . `<redoc spec-url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/json" ></redoc>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done. Just place the input source in a folder that is not served from webpack, this can be found in your webpack config file.

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: "./public/", // this
    watchContentBase: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

And add path in spec-url accordingly.